# Getting an import error in python after using pip install and setting path

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Getting an import error in python after using pip install and setting path in vscode

```
 File "c:\Users\auxyc\Desktop\keylog\keylogger.py", line 1, in <module>
    import keyboard
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keyboard'
```

I have set the path in the settings, and python is in path

EDIT: I have tried to install it via the vscode terminal

Comment: Did you try to install it via the VScode terminal?

Comment: @kabooya yes i have, will edit original question

Comment: And how are you running your Python code, via VScode?

Comment: I have tried bot vscode, through a command prompt, and by double clicking the file. I get an error on all, but when double clicking the file, the command prompt instantly closes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once check if Python 3.7 selected as your interpreter in Visual Studio Code. Try to change it to Python 3.8, then execute once. If still errors exists please let me know